# Skipping a deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to skip over an ajax request (multi pool):

```
        function doRequest(next) {
            if (ajaxOpts.ajaxRequestType == "bla") {
                console.log("next");
                $.Deferred().reject().then(next, next);
            } else {
                jqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxOpts)
                    .done(dfd.resolve)
                    .fail(dfd.reject)
                    .then(next, next);
            }
        }
```

But `$.Deferred().reject().then(next, next);`

Doesn't seem to call the next function. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit : the next function seems to be:

```
 function () {
            jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: Which jQuery version do you use? I'm not able to reproduce. Also if you want anything to be executed in any case - use `.always()`. But in your case - why not to just call `next` function? What for do you reject an empty deferred object?

Comment: I tested and `next` gets correctly called as the `failFilter`. What makes you think that it isin't getting called? Did you check `typeof next` to make sure it's a function at that time? Anyway, why don't you just call `next()`?

Comment: I use jquery 2. I also tried just calling next() but that doesn't work either (its called just once). See original post to see what next function is. It is supposed to execute the next function added to a queue. (so the dequeue call should do that).

Comment: btw, i'm using this plugin: https://github.com/GeReV/jQuery.ajaxMultiQueue

Comment: Why do you need a plugin for this? Won't the browser queue the request by itself if the maximum concurrent request number is reached?

Comment: I have issues on windows when I do 100 ajax request and those requests are for localhost. It slows down to a crawl, yet when I do it with this plugin it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You're using deferred incorrectly, see the examples at jQuery's site:
http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/

Or see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbMQz/1/

```
x = jQuery.Deferred(function(defer){
    defer.reject();
}).then(function(){ alert('1') }, function(){ alert('2') });
```

Comment: It seems the function with alert 2 is called (or in my case the next function), but nothing happens after that, you can see what is in the next function in the original post. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The problem is "elem" in the next function. For some reason it's not set when I don't use the ajax call. any idaes?